# Cacti - after upgrade to 0.8.8a not graphing harddrive space on Windows servers

Tags: monitoring, snmp, net-snmp, cacti

I have upgraded Cacti from 0.8.7g to 0.8.8a. (We use poller not spine).

I followed the upgrade instructions here - http://docs.cacti.net/manual:088:1_installation.3_upgrading#upgrading_cacti

Cacti Server; Linux RedHat server RHEL4connect to mysql
Not using custom scripts basically inbuilt server (index) scripts.

What doesnt graph is hard drive usage (hdtotal/hdfreespace) on windows or linux boxes
Windows servers will only graph network stats not hd/cpu.

I have confirmed that the OID in the Server script directory are correct.  Went through the trouble shooting steps here - http://docs.cacti.net/manual:088:4_help.2_debugging#debugging

Linux server are ok with recording and displaying cpu/network but not hard drive data.

I realise this post is a bit all over the place, but new to cacti and want to fix these issues.  Any information/help is appreciated.  Even if it is just to set up a windows server monitoring graph.

Thanks
Roger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI
We had no luck with this upgrade and ended up rebuilding the server using packages available through redhat repositories.

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 0):

Did you rebuild the poller cache already ?

Go to Console -> System Utilities -> Rebuild Poller Cache

That rebuilds the cache which the poller is using. It sometimes get's not updated properly during an update leaving some graphs empty.

Comment: hi there, thanks for the interest.  Yes i did rebuild the poller cache.  The snmp queries seem to work from the command line, but the graphs dont show.